# "VW kauft Porsche" - Wer kauft hier wen?

Tags: grammatical-case

Die Katze beißt den Hund.
Die Katze beißt der Hund.

Bei maskulinen Substantiven kann ich durch verändern des Artikels den grammatikalischen Fall (?) und somit die Bedeutung/Reihenfolge des Satzes verändern.

Sehe ich richtig, dass das bei femininen und neutralen Substantiven nicht geht und ebenfalls nicht, wenn man keine Artikel im Satz hat, wie z.B. bei Eigennamen?

Die Katze beißt die Maus.
VW kauft Porsche.

Wie kann ich hier den Fall ermitteln oder verstehe ich hier etwa irgendwas komplett falsch?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Theoretisch** kann man in solchen Fällen in der Tat nicht einwandfrei feststellen, wer Subjekt und wer Objekt ist.

**Praktisch** kann man allerdings davon ausgehen, dass das Subjekt so gut wie immer an erster Stelle steht, außer der vorherige Kontext weist deutlich auf das Gegenteil hin (z.B. indem vorher explizit nach dem Objekt gefragt wurde).

> Die Katze frisst die Maus.
>
> VW kauft Porsche.

Kein Kontext: Die Katze und VW sind mit 99-prozentiger Wahrscheinlichkeit das Subjekt des jeweiligen Satzes.

> Wen frisst die Maus? Die Katze frisst die Maus.
>
> Wen kauft Porsche? VW kauft Porsche.

Durch den Kontext (und in der gesprochenen Sprache auch die deutliche Betonung auf "Katze"/"VW") wird deutlich, dass die Katze/VW hier ausnahmsweise die Objekte sind.

Allerdings klingen selbst diese Fälle schon recht seltsam. Im Normalfall würde man ganz einfach eine Passivkonstruktion vorziehen:

> Die Katze wird von der Maus gefressen.
>
> VW wird von Porsche gekauft.

**tl;dr:** Man sollte sich in solchen Fällen nicht unnötig den Kopf zerbrechen und einfach davon ausgehen, dass das Subjekt zuerst kommt, solange nichts für das Gegenteil spricht. Sprache ist Kommunikation, und der Sprecher/Schreiber trägt eine Mitverantwortung, seine Äußerungen möglichst eindeutig zu gestalten. Wer bewusst eine Konstruktion wie "VW kauft Porsche" (mit "Porsche" als Subjekt) verwendet, ist selber Schuld, wenn ihn niemand korrekt versteht.

Comment: Perfekt erklärt.

Comment: Würde ein Komma nicht helfen um den ungewöhnlichen Fall zu verdeutlichen? "Die Katze, frisst die Maus."

Comment: @Arsenal An diese Stelle darf kein Komma gesetzt werden. Und selbst wenn, wäre die Sache dann wirklich einfacher zu entscheiden?  Eventuell könnte man den Satz noch als Ellipse deuten ("Die Katze, *die* frisst die Maus"), und da steht man wieder vor dem gleichen Problem (ist das eingefügte "die" oder "die Maus" das Subjekt?).

Comment: Hmm, mit Kommaregeln bin ich nicht sonderlich bewandert. Ich finde die Sache wesentlich einfacher zu verstehen, wenn da ein Komma steht. Wenn da ein Komma steht, kann es nicht mehr die Katze sein, die die Maus frisst sondern die Maus frisst die Katze. Aber vielleicht ist mein Sprachgefühl auch total daneben.

Comment: @Arsenal Grob gesagt: Kommas trennen entweder Aufzählungen (=die voneinander getrennten Teile können in ihrer Reihenfolge umgeordnet werden) oder Ergänzungen (=einer der Teile *muss* ein kompletter Satz sein). Beides träfe auf "Die Katze, frisst die Maus." nicht zu.

Comment: @Arsenal Ausnahme von dieser Fausregel: Die direkte Rede ("'Die Katze', sagte die Maus."). Wahrscheinlich hast du deinen Satz analog dazu gebildet. In dieser Konstruktion ist der untergeordnete Satzteil allerdings immer eine "Rede", was hier auch nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: Vielleicht öffne ich einfach eine neue Frage hierzu - nicht weil ich diese Satzkonstruktion besonders attraktiv finde, sondern weil ich die Problematik sich möglichst eindeutig auszudrücken sehr interessant finde.

Answer (score 8):

> Die Maus frisst die Katze.

Wenn es kein Märchen oder Bericht vom LSD-Traum ist, erkennen wir hier, dass die Katze das Subjekt ist, aus dem Kontext.

> VW kauft Porsche.

Hier erkennen wir nichts. Allerdings ist die Form, in der das erste das Subjekt ist, sehr viel gebräuchlicher. Wenn wir jetzt aus Meldungen der letzten Tage nichts gegenteiliges wissen, würden wir annehmen, dass VW hier das Subjekt ist.

Comment: Ich würde noch erwähnen, ob das im Allgemeinen eindeutig ist (würde ich nicht sagen), dass man auch schreiben könnte "Die Katze frisst die Maus" und meinen würde, dass die Maus von der Kartze gefressen wird, und dass dies im Gesprochenen durch Betonung geregelt wird.

Comment: Ich würde sagen im Allgemeinen ist es eindeutig. "Petra streicht die Leiter", "Die Küchenmaschine beherbergt die Küche", "die Arie singt die Sängerin". Dass es im Ausnahmefall unklar ist ergibt ja der Verweis auf Märchen usw. Das mit der Betonung schien mir erst eine gute Idee, bis ich es ausprobierte. "Die Klara küsst die Inge" kann ich nicht so betonen, dass klar wird, wer wen küsst. "Maus und Amsel gingen aus. Die Amsel griff ein Adler, die Maus fraß die Katze." Sicher macht dieser Kontext nicht, dass hier nicht Supermaus in Aktion war, aber die Konstruktion legt nahe, die Maus geht hops.